# What is the behaviour of this C code snippet?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Recently I saw following piece code:

```
if ((rgb = (fp16 *)malloc(width*height*sizeof (*rgb)*3)) == NULL)
```

rgb is declared as a pointer of some class type. 
In the above code, malloc() is taking arguments which is width*height*sizeof(*rgb)

So it is some kind of self referential initialization(If i may call it by giving this name!)
i.e. belore rgb pointer is allocated by malloc, it is dereferencing it in call to malloc.

In this particular code, i saw that the pointer rgb is not initialized to NULL or anything.

What would be the behaviour of such code.

- Normal functioning or
- Crash due to null pointer dereference, or a
- Garage pointer dereference

thanks,

-AD.

Comment: `sizeof` is a compiler EDIT: operator, not a function call, so `rgb` is never dereferenced, the compiler just used the expression to determine the value of `sizeof`

Comment: @up, if you post an answer as a comment, the OP cannot accept it. :)

Comment: @cthom06: `sizeof` is not a macro; it's an operator.

Comment: And sizeof is computed at runtime, not compile time.

Comment: @Kos I don't really know why I didn't think that merited being an answer. There's plenty now anyways.

Comment: @Charles you're right, of course it's not a macro, the preprocessor doesn't know anything about types, corrected.

Comment: @Time Machine: Nope.  sizeof calculations are done at compile time.  It's only at compile time that you know the size of whatever it is the pointer points to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` does not evaluate its operand, so in this case `sizeof(*rgb)` will return the size of `rgb`'s type, which I assume is `fp16 *`.

Completely valid C code.

If it did evaluate it and the pointer was just some declared pointer with no initialized value, then you would get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually dereferencing the pointer, `sizeof(*rgb)` does a compile-time determination of the size of the type pointed to by `rgb`.  The machine code generated by that line will use a literal number in place of the `sizeof(*rgb)` term.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` doesn't evaluate its argument. It only computes its size. So you don't get the *undefined behaviour* associated to uninitialized pointer dereferentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the if block would not happen when malloc succeeds. If malloc fails, the block will be executed.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted:

> i saw that the pointer rgb is not
>   initialized to NULL or anything.

if rgb is initialized to NULL, then it will go through that `if` condition.

That is code line is fine.